# Flitter vs. Flutter

Tags: word-choice

Do I say *flitter* or *flutter* when referring to the opening of eyes as used in this sentence?

> Her eyes flittered open as I knocked gently on her door.

I have read up on three different answers:

1. They are the same and *flitter* is used less.
2. *Flutter* means something different to *flitter*, supporting *flutter* in this context.
3. *Flutter* means something different to *flitter*, supporting flitter in this context.

Comment: Normally "flutter" is used when referencing eyelids, but one might choose to use "flitter" to imply a degree of randomness.  "Flutter", in it's literal sense, means to flap like a butterfly or bird, while "flitter" implies moving about from, eg, one flower to the next, in a random fashion.

Comment: There's also to _flit_, which bears a similar meaning; you might consider adding this to your question.

Comment: Flutter.  But please edit your question.  "Her eyes flittered open as a gentle knock came at the door."  You have to decide where your narrator is sitting -- inside the room or outside?

Comment: @aparente001 I changed the piece to imply the door was already open and the narrator (father) was giving a courteous knock at the door and, whether unanswered or answered, would be entered. I hope that makes it clearer, but let me know if I should change it further.

Comment: @vanderpn I've only ever seen the word written. 'Flitted' and 'flittered' sound essentially the same in Australian speech, so I think that may be what I'm going for, actually.

Comment: Tyson, your narrator can apparently see through doors....

Answer (score -1):

I get an eerie sense that you might be a better writer than me. You may be writing something much denser than what I write. But my opinion, for what it's worth, would be to go with "flitter." According to the definitions, "flitter" seems to overlap a lot with "flutter," yet as you mentioned, "flitter" implies randomness. I also noticed that "flitter" may not connote butterflies as much as "flutter" does, but this is just a conclusion I reached after reading the definitions. But personally, I like the sentence better as you originally wrote it, because it illustrates the kind of randomness of quick blinking when someone is abruptly awoken from a nap.

Comment: Personally, your opinion would be worth more to me if you had any evidence to buttress it. Dictionary definitions that differentiate between the words? Examples of usage? (And I don't know whom you're addressing, but the OP didn't mention randomness. That was HL.)

Comment: But shouldn't that read, "...a better writer than I [am]"? And "...than what I write" sounds just like Ernie Wise's running gag in the comedy routine of the much loved British entertainers, Morecambe and Wise.

Comment: If you are trying to imply that I was sarcastically complimenting the OP, you are wrong. I was just writing what came to mind. The OP just so happened to be searching for a very specific difference between two somewhat similar words, and I honestly felt like they may be writing something cool. I just write for the purpose of school, and I use this website as a resource.

Comment: And on the topic of the comment about evidence, I DELIBERATELY stated words such as, "But my opinion, for what it's worth, would be..." and "but this is just a conclusion I reached after reading the definitions," and "But personally." I based my conclusions on the definitions of the words, and I specifically stated that it was only my opinion. I intentionally stated that it was just my personal thoughts. I used the definitions of the words to help answer the question that the OP asked.